# Why does %d show two different values for *b and *c in the code [b and c points to same address]

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the Code below

```
{
float a=7.999,*b,*c;
b=&a;c=b;
printf("%d-b\n%d-c\n%d-a\n",*b,*c,a);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
-536870912-b
1075838713-c
-536870912-a
```

I know we are not allowed to use %d instead of %f, but why does *b and *c give two different values? 
Both have the same address, can someone explain?
I want to know the logic behind it

Comment: You are observering the mysteries of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @alk - Why don't you at least extend the courtesy of explaining "undefined behavior"?

Comment: As the OP seems to fully be aware entering unsecure territory ... @FoggyDay

Comment: On your machines, does sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)?  If it doesn't then the second %d may be printing part of *b instead of *c.  As mentioned by others - it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @cup:Yes size of float and integer are same[4 bytes]

Comment: But `float` expressions passed to the ellipsis get promoted to `double` (and `%f` processes a `double`, not a `float`).

Comment: `floats`s get promoted to double here.

Comment: If you really want to know what happens, look at the generated assembly code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simplified example of your ordeal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  float a=7.999, b=7.999;
  printf("%d-a\n%d-b\n",a,b);
}
```

What's happening is that `a` and `b` are converted to doubles (8 bytes each) for the call to printf (since it is variadic). Inside the printf function, the given data, 16 bytes, is printed as two 4-byte ints. So you're printing the first and second half of one of the given double's data as ints.

Try changing the `printf` call to this and you'll see both halves of both doubles as ints:

```
  printf("%d-a1\n%d-a2\n%d-b1\n%d-b2\n",a,b);
```

I should add that as far as the standard is concerned, this is simply "undefined behavior", so the above interpretation (tested on gcc) would apply only to certain implementations.

Comment: Or how about a1, a2, b1, b2 instead of a, b, a, b?

Comment: I used: `printf("%d-%d-b\n%d-%d-c\n%d-%d-a\n",*b,*c,a);`


and output was:

**-536870912-1075838713-b**
**-536870912-1075838713-c**
**-536870912-1075838713-a**

Answer (score 2):

Using wrong conversion specification invokes undefined behavior. You may get either expected or unexpected value. Your program may crash, may give different result on different compiler or any unexpected behavior.

#### C11: 7.21.6 Formatted input/output functions:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) If any argument is
> not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.

Comment: The answer might have been downvoted as it also does not give any specific reason for what the OP's actually observers in particular, as other answers/comment do.

Comment: @alk; If behavior is undefined then all bets are off!

Comment: @alk; If so then C standard must remove this quote or should modify it.

Comment: I was referring to "*all bets are off*", as there **could** be "extensions", or at least predictable behaviour for one or the other implementation.

Answer (score 2):

There can be any number of reasons.

The most obvious -- your platform passes some integers in integer registers and some floating point numbers in floating point registers, causing `printf` to look in registers that have never been set to any particular value.

Another possibility -- the variables are different sizes. So `printf` is looking in data that wasn't set or was set as part of some other operation.

Because `printf` takes its parameters through `...`, type agreement is essential to ensure the implementation of the function is even looking in the right places for its parameters.

You would have to have deep knowledge of your platform and/or dig into the generated assembly code to know for sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Bad
float a=7.999,*b,*c;
b=&a;c=b;
printf("%d-b\n%d-c\n%d-a\n",*b,*c,a);

// Good
float a=7.999,*b,*c;
b=&a;c=b;
printf("%f-b\n%f-c\n%f-a\n",*b,*c,a);
```

Using an integer format specified "%d" instead of correctly using a float specified "%f" is what alk elliptically fails to explain as "undefined behavior".

You need to use the correct format specifier.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.